# li inline fill available width

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I want to make li fill available width every line to make both side align.

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJmFL.png)

Here are my html and in-line CSS style.

Is there any CSS way to achieve this effect?

HTML:

```
<div class="row tag-cloud-wrap">
    <div class="col-md-12 content-heading"> 
        <a href="#">
            <h3>
                Find more Content by Keywords
            </h3>
        </a>
        <div class="article-list" style="border: none">
            <ul class="list-inline">
                @foreach($videoData->keywords as $videokeyword)
                <li style="background-color: #999;margin-right: -5px;margin-bottom:0;border-left: 1px solid white; border-bottom: 1px solid white; padding: 5px;">
                    <a style="padding: 5px;" href="#">
                        <strong>{{$videokeyword}}</strong>
                    </a>
                </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I have not described it clear. I want this effect dynamic. for example: if ul width is allowed first line display three li, the last one should automatic fill the rest of line space. If screen size changed, only two element can display in one line, the last one should fill rest space. How Can I do that?

Comment: No CSS can't detect the last element on a breaking row...you would need javascript for that.

Comment: This is possible if each "row" is a separate container though.

Answer (score -1):

On div class article-list set *width* to whatever width you need the block to be.

Then on each *li* element add:

```
display: inline-flex;
```

You may have to play with it a little more to get exactly what you want, but this should get you started.

See: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp  for more information about Flex Boxes.